# Manipulating dot products

Tags: linear-algebra

I know that vectors $a$ and $b$, $a \cdot b = b^Ta$.

So, for a $n \times  n$ matrix $A$, and vectors $x$ and $y$
$$ (Ax) \cdot (Ay) = (Ay)^T (Ax) =y^T (A^T Ax) = (A^T Ax) \cdot  y^T = (A^T A) (x \cdot  y^T)$$

Is this correct? In particular, I know $(ax) \cdot y = a (x \cdot y)$ for $a \in \mathbb{R} $, does this work for matrices?

Comment: Your last equality looks dubious. The last quantity seems to be an $n\times n$ matrix times a scalar, so presumably is an $n\times n$ matrix, while all preceding terms seem to be scalars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\newcommand \trans {^\mathsf T}
v \cdot (Mw) = w\trans M\trans v = w\trans (M\trans v) = (M\trans v) \cdot w, 
$$
now plug them in.